# can you please see if my solution is correct for the folowing equation

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

The equation is

$   z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z=0  $

I  tried to solve it that way 
$z(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+z+1)=0  $
then

No root was found algebraically
so $z=0$ !!!!
Am I right here?
Special thanks to all of you.

Comment: Do you consider complex roots? Your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955296/solve-this-equation-in-complex-no-and-write-the-answer-in-polar-and-rectangular) were about complex roots.

Comment: What does "No root was found algebraically" mean (like, not *in English*, but *in actual facts*)?

Comment: (Same hint as the previous question) Note that $$z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1 = \frac{z^7-1}{z-1}.$$
And $z=1$ is not a root on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have this factored so you are on your way to solving it. If you have an
expression in the form of $ab = 0$. Then we know that either $a = 0$, $b = 0$ or they are both $0$. You have: $z(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+z+1)=0$

So one root is $z = 0$. To find the other roots, you need to solve this equation:
$z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+z+1=0$.

I suspect that $0$ is the only real root.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

From here

$$z(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)=0 \iff z=0 \,\lor\, z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$$

then note that

$$z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=\frac{z^7-1}{z-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You also have six more roots in complex plane.

Note that $$ z^7-1=(z-1)(z^6+z^5+...+z+1)$$

Thus the seven-th roots of unity except $z=1$ are also solutions to your equation .